# Results view does not change with zoom feature in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2012

The zoom feature in SQL Server Management Studio is not changing the results window. I have come across many posts that say the zoom controls both the query window and the results window.

What do I need to change so the zoom controls both?

[image: zoom not working]

Answer (score 16):

You can change the "Messages" tab using the zoom control within that tab, however the same is not true for the "Results" tab.

One way to change the font size is via:

Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors

Here you can configure the fonts for every aspect of SQL Server. In your case select "Grid Results" from the drop down menu, then change the font size. You probably also need to close and reopen SSMS for the changes to pickup.

[image: Fonts and Colors Settings]

Answer (score 0):

The results window has a separate Zoom dropdown. The one you are changing is the Zoom for Text Editor window. A similar Zoom dropdown is available below the results window, you can control the zoom level for result window from there.

Comment: This is wrong, at least for version 2012 the question was about.